# Smach without ROS

Tags: smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing some tests with smach and I didn't want to pull in ROS yet. In the [wiki](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach) it says that smach is ROS independent. However, in util.py there is a "#import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('smach')" that doesn't make it so. I commented it out, but I am not sure if everything will work fine.

Is loading the manifest necessary to run smach? Can it be really ROS-independent?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9832/smach-without-ros/) by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1342 on 2011-04-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Smach package can be used independent of ROS. I believe the import of roslib in the util.py is actually an oversight, and it should be removed. I fixed this in the default branch of the executive_smach stack, and am running our entire regression test set to verify that nothing relies on the import.  I filed [this ticket](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/4939) to track the problem.

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2